# Fast redrawing with PyQt and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, blit

I'm trying to create GUI-app with real-time data visualization.

The solution I came up with is to use well-known trick with partial redrawing:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)

axes[0].set_{labels, limits}
axes[1].set_{labels, limits}    

fig.show()
fig.canvas.draw()
N = 2
graph_0 = axes[0].scatter([] * N, [] * N, s=[np.pi*5**2] * N, animated=True)
graph_1 = axes[1].scatter([] * N, [] * N, s=[np.pi*5**2] * N, animated=True)
bg_0 = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(axes[0].bbox)
bg_1 = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(axes[1].bbox)

while True:

    # Acquire new data
    tmp = [1, 2]  # *For example*

    # Clear plots
    fig.canvas.restore_region(bg_0)
    fig.canvas.restore_region(bg_1)

    # Set data to be visualized
    graph_0.set_offsets([(i+1, d) for i, d in enumerate(tmp)])
    graph_1.set_offsets([(i+1, d) for i, d in enumerate(tmp)])

    # Redraw
    axes[0].draw_artist(graph_0)
    axes[1].draw_artist(graph_1)
    fig.canvas.blit(axes[0].bbox)
    fig.canvas.blit(axes[1].bbox)
```

This solution is OK and everything works fine.

After that I tried to implement the same approach but using PyQt backend (to add also some control elements).

Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.uic import loadUiType

import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import (
    FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas)

Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow = loadUiType('dialog.ui')


class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.layout_mpl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.widget_mpl.setLayout(self.layout_mpl)

        # Assign callbacks
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.update_figure)
        self.prepare_figure()

    def prepare_figure(self):
        self.fig, self.axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.layout_mpl.addWidget(self.canvas)
        # self.canvas.draw()

        self.axes[0].set_{labels, limits}
        self.axes[1].set_{labels, limits}    

        self.graph = [None] * 2
        N = 5
        self.graph[0] = self.axes[0].scatter(
            [] * N, [] * N, s=[np.pi*5**2] * N, animated=True)
        self.graph[1] = self.axes[1].scatter(
            [] * N, [] * N, s=[np.pi*5**2] * N, animated=True)

        self.canvas.draw()
        self.bg = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.fig.bbox)

        # self.bg = [None] * 2
        # self.bg[0] = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.fig.axes[0].bbox)
        # self.bg[1] = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.fig.axes[1].bbox)


    def update_figure(self):
        # self.canvas.restore_region(self.bg[0])
        # self.canvas.restore_region(self.bg[1])
        self.canvas.restore_region(self.bg)   

        # Set data to be visualized
        self.graph[0].set_offsets([(i+1, d) for i, d in
                                   enumerate(np.random.rand(5)*100+100)])
        self.graph[1].set_offsets([(i+1, d) for i, d in
                                   enumerate(np.random.rand(5)*100+100)])

        # Redraw
        self.axes[0].draw_artist(self.graph[0])
        self.axes[1].draw_artist(self.graph[1])

        self.canvas.blit(self.axes[0].bbox)
        self.canvas.blit(self.axes[1].bbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You might see different combinations of calls I used under commented lines.

So, I expect on every click of `button` the plots to be updated. It actually works, except one blocking issue:

a) Application just started

[image]

b) Button has been clicked once

[image]

c) Switched focus to another window and back (this plot is the one with offset, but the points are placed in old coordinates)

[image]

Could someone give any directions, please?

Thanks in advance!

Versions used: Python 3.4.3, matplotlib 1.4.3, PyQt 4.10.4 .

Comment: Everything you're doing looks correct. I'm not 100% sure where your problem is coming from, but one issue that could cause it is that you're not updating your background (`self.bg`) when/if the canvas is resized.  This will result in the wrong region being restored, if the figure has been resized in anyway.

Comment: @JoeKington My main window (`Dialog`) has fixed size, has to check for the `Widget` though... The thing is when I click button several times, points are still being generated in the old coordinates, while grid, axes and labels are being redrawn in the ones with offset. That's why I think it is most likely a `matplotlib` issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to constanly check and update `axes.bbox` sizes:

http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/old_animation/animation_blit_qt4.html

Comment: I was confused, this isn't actually fixed in 1.5

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are grabbing the background at some point before it is fully re sized etc to what is going to end up on the screen.  What you need to do is

- use `draw_idle` to let Qt decide when to actually trigger the full redraw
- use the mpl event stack to grab the background after that draw

Just the relevant methods:

```
    def prepare_figure(self):
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.axes.set_xlim((0, 6))
        self.axes.set_xlabel('seq.index')
        self.axes.set_ylim((0, 100))
        self.axes.set_ylabel('observation')

        N = 5
        self.graph = self.axes.scatter(
            [] * N, [] * N, s=[np.pi*5**2] * N,
            color='seagreen', animated=True)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        # w = self.widget_mpl.width()
        # h = self.widget_mpl.height()
        # self.canvas.setFixedSize(w, h)

        self.layout_mpl.addWidget(self.canvas)

        # hook up to mpls event handling framework for draw events
        # this is emitted after the canvas has finished a full redraw
        self.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self._draw_event)

        # ask the canvas to kindly draw it self some time in the future
        # when Qt thinks it is convenient
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def _draw_event(self, evt):
        # after drawing, grab the new background
        self.bg = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.axes.bbox)
```

Have a look at the blitting code in the `animation` module for a full set of the functions you need to make this work (there is also a re-size event) and after a force re-draw you will need to re-blit what ever the last data was.

Comment: isn't this approach more complicated than the one in `old_animation` example? what does act as trigger to re-draw in your case?

Comment: This ensures that you only grab a new background after it as been correctly redrawn.  In this case, the full draw is triggered by the repaint logic in Qt (ex, a figure resize).